# How to get mobile country code using ip address in php

Tags: php, ip

I have to get the mobile country code based on ip i.e,
For India => 91, England => 41 etc. I have used below code but its not working.

Code,

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$data = file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=" . $ip);
$data = json_decode($data);
```

Comment: @aniket can u please tell how to do using curl

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: I believe you are referring to "IDD country code" instead of "mobile country code". Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

It is giving following response

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$data = file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=" . $ip);
$data = json_decode($data);
print_($data);

Repsone

{
  ["geoplugin_request"]=>
  string(13) "XX.XX.XX.XXX"
  ["geoplugin_status"]=>
  int(200)
  ["geoplugin_credit"]=>
  string(143) "Some of the returned data includes GeoLite data created by MaxMind, available from <a href='http://www.maxmind.com'>http://www.maxmind.com</a>."
  ["geoplugin_city"]=>
  string(9) "New Delhi"
  ["geoplugin_region"]=>
  string(5) "Delhi"
  ["geoplugin_areaCode"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["geoplugin_dmaCode"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["geoplugin_countryCode"]=>
  string(2) "IN"
  ["geoplugin_countryName"]=>
  string(5) "India"
  ["geoplugin_continentCode"]=>
  string(2) "AS"
  ["geoplugin_latitude"]=>
  string(4) "28.6"
  ["geoplugin_longitude"]=>
  string(4) "77.2"
  ["geoplugin_regionCode"]=>
  string(2) "07"
  ["geoplugin_regionName"]=>
  string(5) "Delhi"
  ["geoplugin_currencyCode"]=>
  string(3) "INR"
  ["geoplugin_currencySymbol"]=>
  string(7) "&#8360;"
  ["geoplugin_currencySymbol_UTF8"]=>
  string(3) "₨"
  ["geoplugin_currencyConverter"]=>
  float(64.1725)
}
```

From the above you will get the country geoplugin_countryCode which is iso code,

once you have iso country code , u can easily get country country dialing code  code. (Keep the array of dailing coutry code and iso code map)
example

$country = array ('IN'=>91,......);

i wish this will help